# How to merge multiple datagridview column into one in windows forms app which contains some dynamic controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem of merging multiple columns of data gridview into one. My data gridview contains some dynamic controls also added based on some conditions (e.g. Drop down and Textbox).

I am using windows forms and I want to a achieve a layout that looks like this:

[image: Diagram]

Note that there is a vertical stack of controls in one cell of the grid.

How can I achieve that?

"Really_Long_file_name_of_the_Attachment.doc" is a non-editable text box.

FORM_TYPE_DROPDOWN is a dropdown with about 100 different selections.  Each selection can be quite wide (maybe 60 characters)

"Claims description if claims is selected" is a text box that can accept up to 60 characters of input.  It is an optional field.

"Message about the attachment" is a placeholder for an error or warning message if there is something wrong with the file.

The problem Dipak is trying to solve is getting those 4 controls in one cell of a grid.

Comment: [How to: Customize Cells and Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control by Extending Their Behavior and Appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/customize-cells-and-columns-in-the-datagrid-by-extending-behavior).

Comment: It looks like the job of a UserControl set as the content of a DataGridView Cell: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells). Unless it's just a bunch of strings what you have there.

Comment: Please check the details as specified below regarding of information column.

**1) Really_Long_File_name_of_the_attachment.doc - Display directly from data table.
2) FORM_TYPE_DROPDOWN have the type "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn" - Added dynamically in datagridview.
3) Claims Description have the type "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn" - Added dynamically in datagridview.
4) Message about the attachment - Display directly from data table.**

Right now this all information displayed in separate column but i need to display all four different column values in one column in the format as specified.

Comment: Can you switch to TableLayoutPanel to control the layout of controls?